# настройка owl-carousel 2

Tags: jquery, плагин

Всем привет. Кто может подсказать - привинчиваю на сайт слайдер. Выбрал owl-carousel 2 последнюю. Есть пара нюансов. Как бы не старался, кнопки впередназад не работают, точнее у них в инлайновых стилях стоит disable/ Пробовал в настройках плагина ставить nav в значение и true и false и один и тот же результат. Второе, в блоках слайдера разнородный контент(изображение и тексты - это отзывы), как сделать чтобы высота блоков была одинаковой, не зависимо от того, больше в каком-то текста или меньше?Есть какая-то настройка на это?жестко задавать высоту не хочу, потому что все же адаптив, а с кучей медиазапросов ковыряться не хочется, да и количество контента может измениться. За ответ буду благодарен.

Comment: По поводу того что не работает нужен код например на codepen или еще куда выложите (можно сюда).
По поводу высоты блоков - нет такой опции

Comment: Для стрелок смотри классы owl-carousel owl-theme и проверь наличие js, css от owl carousel и чтобы они стояли после jquery. Для настройки высоты нет такой опции, используй цсс, например display:flex;

Comment: проблема в том, что flexы там перекрываются самим слайдером..плагин ведь создает свои обертки для элементов и не получается..пробовал..с кнопками вопрос решил по своему, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();

$('.arrow__right').click(function() {
        owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});

$('.arrow__left').click(function() {
        owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
})
```

arrow__right и arrow__left - кнопки, которые можно разместить где угодно.

Подробнее: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html